# Spring MVC Dependency Injection Understanding

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I am new to Spring MVC.I am learning the concept of dependency Injection.I am following this link for the code example of Spring using dependency Injection.

[Spring Example](https://www.boraji.com/spring-dependency-injection-example-with-xml-configuration)

In that example i was very clear of the concept of dependency Injection. But i have a small question on how to tell Spring that i want to use multiple shapes. In that First example (Constructor based) he gave a reference to a Circle Object so that it draws a circle.

```
<bean id="geometryExample1" class="com.boraji.tutorail.spring.GeometryExample1">
    <constructor-arg ref="circleShape"/>
</bean>
```

But what if  want to draw both Circle,Rectangle and other Shapes? how do i tell or configure in Spring that depending on what shape i have provided it should use the approriate shape to draw the shape.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with Spring. The logic how to draw a shape is encapsulated in each of its subclasses. `GeometryExample1` does not and should not know how to draw a shape, it only calls the `draw` method that has different implementation based on the `Shape` instance passed to it.

Answer (score 1):

Please find a tutorial that uses Java config instead of XML config.  Your life will be much easier if you learn to use Java config.

When autowiring you can specify a `@Qualifier` and reference the bean by the id, e.g.

```
// This is your circle object
@Autowired
@Qualifier("geometryExample1")
public GeometryExample1 circleShape;
```

If you had

```
<bean id="squareExample" class="com.boraji.tutorail.spring.GeometryExample1">
    <constructor-arg ref="squareShape"/>
</bean>
```

...then in your code you'd have this:

```
// This is your square object
@Autowired
@Qualifier("squareExample")
public GeometryExample1 squareShape;
```

See [How to autowire by name in Spring with annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36183624/how-to-autowire-by-name-in-spring-with-annotations) for a little more detail and an example of instantiating a bean using Java config.

Comment: Hi @Paul thanks a lot for the suggestion. i will learn annotation based configuration too. But Can you please help how can i pass Multiple shapes here instead of one please?

Comment: also how can i configure in spring in sucha  way that it accepts multiple shapes? @Paul

Comment: The answer by @KamilNoster seems complete - please try that and comment if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Implement your classes:

```
class CircleShape implements Shape {
    void draw() {
        // TODO implementation
    }
}

class RectangleShape implements Shape {
    void draw() {
        // TODO implementation
    }
}
```

Declare beans:

```
<bean id="rectangleShape" class="com.boraji.tutorail.spring.RectangleShape" />
<bean id="rectangleShape" class="com.boraji.tutorail.spring.CircleShape" />

<bean id="geometryExample1" class="com.boraji.tutorail.spring.GeometryExample1">
    <constructor-arg ref="rectangleShape"/>
</bean>
```

Java methods are virtual, so draw() from RectangleShape is called.
Change geometryExample1 bean constructor arg back to CircleShape:

```
<bean id="geometryExample1" class="com.boraji.tutorail.spring.GeometryExample1">
    <constructor-arg ref="circleShape"/>
</bean>
```

Now draw() from CircleShape is called.

Read more about virtual methods [here](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/java/virtual-function-in-java/). And use annotations, please.

I hope I understood your problem correctly.

EDIT:
Example class:

```
class GeometryExample1 {
    private Set<Shape> shapes;

    void example() {
        shapes.foreach(Shape::draw);
    }

    public void setShapes(Set<Shape> shapes) {
         this.shapes = shapes;
    }

    public Set<Shape> getShapes() {
        return shapes;
    }
 }
```

And bean declaration:

```
<bean id="geometryExample1" class="com.boraji.tutorail.spring.GeometryExample1">
    <property name="shapes">
        <set>
            <ref bean="circleShape" />
            <ref bean="rectangleShape" />
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

In this case, annotation config should be way more clear.

Comment: Thanks. But what if i want to draw a circle and rectangle one after other? We can not go back and change the configuration for each shape . So Can you please exaplain how will be the configuration and using them ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But there can be special scenario's right? Like What if i just want to draw rectangle once and both rectangle and circle once? So i should make changes in this case in cnfiguration. So is there a dynamic way just to pass it to the Shape object and can pass multiple shapes to the same object ?